# Maximum value of $x+2 x y+4 x y z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Given that $x,y,z \in R^+$ such that $x+y+z=1.5$. Without using calculus find the maximum value of $x+2 x y+4 x y z $

My try:
We can write $S=x+2 x y+4 x y z =x(1+2y+4yz)$

$\implies$
$$S=x((1+2y)(1+2z)-2z)$$
$\implies$
$$S=\frac{1}{2}(1+2 x-1)(1+2 y)(1+2 z)-2 x z$$
$\implies$
$$S=\frac{1}{2}(1+2 x)(1+2 y)(1+2 z)-\frac{1}{2}(1+2 y)(1+2z)-2xz$$
By $AM-G.M$, we have
$$(1+2 x)(1+2 y)(1+2 z) \leq\left(\frac{3+2(x+y+z)}{3}\right)^{3}$$
$\implies$
$$(1+2 x)(1+2 y)(1+2 z) \leq 8$$
Any hint from here?

Comment: Note: The supremum does not occur at $ x = y = z $, so you should modify your approach accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to reduce the number of variables.
EG We could use the substitution $ z = 3/2 - y - x $ to make this a 2 variable inequality.
How can we make this a 1 variable inequality?

Work through the following. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

---

1. (In hindsight, because) The maximum occurs at $ (1, 0.5, 0)$, so we will allow for non-negative reals (or deal with finding the supremum instead, your choice).
2. We use a substitution $ 2x = a, 2y = b, 2c = z$ to simplify the problem

> $a+b+c = 3$ are non-negative reals, what is the maximum of $a+ab+abc$?

3. Suppose that $  b + c = k$, how can we maximize $ b+ bc$? What is it's value in terms of $k$?

> Since $ b +bc = b ( 1+c ) = b ( 1 + k - b) \leq (\frac{ 1 + k}{2} )^2 $, hence the maximum occurs when $ b = 1+c = \frac{k+1}{2}$.
>  The max value is $\frac{1}{4} (k+1)^2$.

4. Hence, what is the maximum of $ a ( 1 + b+bc) $, subject to $ b+c = 3-a$?

> We want to find the maximum of $ a ( 1 + \frac{1}{4} ( 4 - a ) ^2 ) $, subject to $ 0 \leq a \leq 3$.

Use your favorite approach to maximize the above cubic in a restricted range.
The goal is to find the turning points of the cubic. Once we have those, we can check against the end points to find the max/min.
I personally would use calculus here, but that's not absolutely necessary:

> Consider $Y(a) = a^3 - 8a^2 +20a $, which is our expanded cubic after multiplying by 4.
>  We want to find a $D$ such that $Y - D = a^3 - 8a^2 + 20a - D$ can be written in the form $ (a - p)(a-q)^2 $, then $ a = q$ will be a turning point.
>  Expanding and equating terms, we have $ p+2q = 8, q(2p+q) = 20, pq^2 = D$.
>  Solving the first 2 equations and substituting it into the 3rd, we have 2 solutions: $ ( p,q, D ) = (4, 2, 16), ( 4/3, 10/3, 400/27)$.
>  So the local maximum is at $a = 2$, the local minimum is at $ a = 10/3$.
>  Finally, the maximum of $ Y(a)$ on $[0,3]$ is the max of $ Y(0), Y(2), Y(3)$, which is 16.

Hence, the maximum occurs at $ a = 2, b = 1, c = 0$.
Substituting this back, we get   $ x + 2xy + 4xyz \leq 2$ with equality at $ (1, 0.5, 0)$.

Comment: Can you amend your answer to give an explicit procedure for maximizing a cubic, without Calculus?  I am curious about this myself.

Comment: @user2661923 One method is to write the cubic as $g (a - h)^3 + k (a - h)^2 + m$. If there are two possible ways to do this, the one with $k < 0$ is the maximum. Doing this will require solving a quadratic in $h$.

Comment: Very interesting response, thanks.

Comment: @user2661923 I added an approach. As expected, it boils down to how one can understand cubics and their turning points without resorting to calculus.

Comment: Yes i used the maximum value of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c,a<0$ as $\frac{-D}{4a}$, where $D$ is the discriminant. So when $b+c=k$, $b+bc=-b^2+b(1+k) \leq  \frac{(1+k)^2}{4}$. Now subject to $b+c=3-a$ we get $a+a(b+bc) \leq a+a\frac{(4-a)^2}{4}=\frac{a^3-8a^2+20a}{4}$. Using derivatives i got suitable critical point of $a$ as $a=2$. So the maximum of $a(1+b+bc)$ is $4$.