# Given non-negative real numbers, $a, b, c$, show that $2a + 2ab + abc \leq 18$ when $a + b + c = 5$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Given non-negative real numbers $a, b, c$, show that
> $$2a + 2ab + abc \leq 18$$
> when $a + b + c = 5$

I have already started with AM-GM inequality, but now I am stuck.

From AM-GM inequality, I found that

$$abc \leq \frac{125}{27}$$

but now I am not sure what I have other two terms to finish the proof.

Maybe I am going in the wrong direction. Please help and thank you. It will be great if you can show a step-by-step solution.

Comment: It's often helpful to find the equality condition, which then suggests what to try (and what not to try). In this case, equality occurs at $ a = 3, b = 2, c = 0 $, so knowing that $ abc \leq 125/27$ when $ a = b = c = 5/3$ will likely not be that helpful.

Comment: Try adapting my approach to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151240/maximum-value-of-x2-x-y4-x-y-z/4151288#4151288). Given the very similar setup, I'm guessing that this could work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to reduce the number of variables, [adapting from this other solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151240/maximum-value-of-x2-x-y4-x-y-z/4151288#4151288).

1. Suppose that $b+c = k$, how can we maximize $2b + bc $? What is the maximum value in terms of $k$?

> $ 2b + bc = b (2+c)  =  b ( 2 + k - b ) \leq ( \frac{2+k}{2} ) ^2$.
>  The maximum occurs when $ b = 2 + c = \frac{k+2}{2}$, with maximum value $ \frac{1}{4} ( k+2)^2$.

2. Hence, for fixed $a$, what is the maximum of $ a(2+2b+bc)$ subject to $b+c = 5 - a$?

> It is $ a ( 2 + \frac{1}{4} ( 7-a)^2)$.

3. For $ a \in [ 0, 5 ]$, what is the maximum of the above cubic?

> Using calculus, the maximum occurs when $a = 3$ (with $ b = 2, c = 0$) and has value 18.
>  If you don't want a calculus approach, see the link for how to maximize a cubic.

Comment: I notice how you can use the non-calculus approach to maximize a cubic; however, the approach does not seem to work when we have a cubic polynomial like $Y = x^3 + 3x$. Is there a certain rule to say we can use $Y - D = P - D$, where $P = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$?

Comment: @JasonChiu In the question you posted, Trefor's comment about checking monotonicity via the quadratic is a good approach.