# Prove that $2a + 2ab + abc \leq 18$ when $a + b + c = 5$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ without calculus.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cubics

I have already had help with proving the conditional statement on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187100/given-non-negative-real-numbers-a-b-c-show-that-2a-2ab-abc-leq-18-w).

Apparently, it includes the following trick from [this website](https://www.themathdoctors.org/max-and-min-of-a-cubic-without-calculus/), and it says it works for any cubic polynomial function.

However, it does not seem to be true for any cubic polynomial function such as $P = x^3 + 3x$. This gives me some doubt of using a similar approach shown on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151240/maximum-value-of-x2-x-y4-x-y-z/4151288#4151288) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187100/given-non-negative-real-numbers-a-b-c-show-that-2a-2ab-abc-leq-18-w).

I was wondering if there is another way to prove my statement without calculus or the previous methods from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151240/maximum-value-of-x2-x-y4-x-y-z/4151288#4151288) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187100/given-non-negative-real-numbers-a-b-c-show-that-2a-2ab-abc-leq-18-w).

If so, please show another step-by-step solution. Thank you!

As you can see, I was trying the AM-GM inequality before, but I got stuck.

Comment: Uh, $x^3 + 3x$ is monotonic, so you don't need that method at all. Just prove that $P(x) > P(y)$ whenever $x>y$ by directly expanding the definition.

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM
$$2a+2ab+abc=a(2+b(2+c))\leq a\left(2+\left(\frac{b+2+c}{2}\right)^2\right)=a\left(2+\left(\frac{7-a}{2}\right)^2\right)\leq18,$$ where the last inequality it's
$$a(57-14a+a^2)\leq72$$ or
$$a^3-14a^2+57a-72\leq0$$ or
$$a^3-6a^2+9a-8a^2+48a-72\leq0$$ or
$$(8-a)(a-3)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Another way.

We need to prove that:
$$\frac{2a(a+b+c)^2}{25}+\frac{2ab(a+b+c)}{5}+abc\leq\frac{18(a+b+c)^3}{125}$$ or
$$18c^3+(44a+54b)c^2+(34a^2-87ab+54b^2)c+2(4a^3-8a^2b-3ab^2+9b^3)\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that:
$$2(22a+27b)c^2+(2a-3b)(17a-18b)c+2(2a-3b)^2(a+b)\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$(17a-18b)^2-16(a+b)(22a+27b)\leq0$$ or $$63a^2+1396ab+108b^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you immediately can say $a \left(2 + \left( \frac{7 - a}{2} \right)^) \right) \leq 18$. Your steps for the last inequality seems to be already assuming that what we are trying to prove is already true.

Comment: @Jason Chiu  See please better your question: We need to prove that $2a+2ab+abc\leq18.$  This way is a shortest way, I think. I see also  another way to the proof, but it's not so nice.

Comment: May I ask what the other way to the proof might be by?

Comment: @Jason Chiu  I added another way. See now.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just answer the specific question of $P(x)=x^3 + 3x$ here.

First we prove that $P(x) > P(y)$ whenever $x>y$:

$$ P(x)-P(y) = x^3-y^3 + 3x-3y = (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+3)$$

But $x^2 + xy + y^2 = x^2( k^2 + k + 1) \ge 0$, where $k = y/x$. The inequality follows from the fact that $k^2 + k + 1 \ge k^2 + k + \frac14 = (k+\frac12)^2 \ge 0$. So the RHS is positive.

So if you restrict $a \le x \le b$, then $P(b)$ will be the maximum, because since $x \le b$, $P(x) \le P(b)$ by our proof above. The minimum is similarly $P(a)$.

Comment: So from the website with TheMathDoctors, are they not entirely correct with what they wrote?

Comment: @JasonChiu The factoring method? That applies whenever the cubic is non-monotonic.